# Problem with bones and Inverse kinematics when scaling

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I have 6 armatures with IK and the last bone is not attached and used as target for the IK
[image]

But when I hit S, expecting the bones would move towards the center, they all move in the same direction along the y axis, any idea why and how to correct ?
( i am using iTaSC as IK solver)
I have tried every transform pivot

[image]

Comment: unfortunately you didn't show us anything of your settings, can u pls provide blend file or copy all relevant informations to your question? thx. you can upload blend file by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and following instructions.

Comment: what setting does your "transform pivot point" have? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dsMo.png -> try using median point

Comment: i downloaded your blend file and pressed `S`, and the bones move towards center correctly so i'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: how did you do ???